# How to customize Create Alert Dialog box in Pine Script v5?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to customize create Alert Dialog box in Pine Script v5 so that I can get the drop down menu under "Condition" column, from where I can choose Long, Short and Exit options. For example just like the following user is getting (Please see the video 1.50m onwards:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z2BdBwF67K0&list=PL2SspAN7iWukVG1INS7-PvcxNd6BlwDWn&index=24

A part of my script which may be relevant to address my query is this:

```
if (longEntryCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
if (longCloseCondition)
    strategy.close("Long")

if (shortEntryCondition)
   strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
if (shortCloseCondition)
   strategy.close("Short")
```

And I tried this:

```
alertcondition(longEntryCondition, title = "Long", message = "Long")
alertcondition(longCloseCondition, title = "Long Exit", message = "Long
```

Exit")
alertcondition(shortEntryCondition, title = "Short", message = "Short")
alertcondition(shortCloseCondition, title = "Short Exit", message =
"Short Exit")

and then this also:

```
alertcondition(longEntryCondition, "Long", "Long")
alertcondition(longCloseCondition, "Long Exit", "Long Exit")
alertcondition(shortEntryCondition, "Short", "Short")
alertcondition(shortCloseCondition, "Short Exit", "Short Exit")
```

But didn't get the dropdown menu.

Then I also tried this:

```
if (longEntryCondition)
    alert("Long", alert.freq_once_per_bar)
if (longCloseCondition)
    alert("Long Close", alert.freq_once_per_bar)
if (shortEntryCondition)
     alert("Short", alert.freq_once_per_bar)
if (shortCloseCondition)
     alert("Short Close", alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

In return I was getting a syntax error. So don't know if these codes can solve my problem.

Hope you'd have understood what I'm trying to get. I'm new to pine script. Please help! Thanks.

Comment: The first two ways you tried look correct. Sometimes you have to remove and then re add the indicator to your chart for it to work.

Comment: I did that. But the dropdown menu still not appearing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use alertcondition with a strategy. You need to convert your code to an indicator for that drop down to work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. From January 2021 TV has introduced a new alert() function that works with both the indicators and the strategy, See video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1hr_dLqxkD8&t=316s. So accordingly I added the following codes in my Strategy: if (longEntryCondition)
    alert("Long", alert.freq_once_per_bar)
if (longCloseCondition)
    alert("Long Close", alert.freq_once_per_bar)
if (shortEntryCondition)
     alert("Short", alert.freq_once_per_bar)
if (shortCloseCondition)
     alert("Short Close", alert.freq_once_per_bar) BUT STILL NOT GETTING THE DROPDOWN MENU.

Comment: UPDATE: I got the dropdown menu but its not as desired. I want four separate alerts for long, long exit, short and short exit. But the alerts dropdown menu is not like that (as in case of indicator).